# Src folder url for font-face CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, font-family

I have one folder that has "styles", and one folder with the actual index.html file. I'm trying to let my index.html file know that the source for my font-face url is inside the "styles" folder.

This is what I have so far:

```
@font-face{
font-family: CHERL___.ttf;
src: url(../Style/CHERL___.ttf);
}
```

I believe that this is incorrect, since it won't load. What is the correct way to identify a file path?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks correct. `.../` goes a folder back, and then `Style/` goes to a folder called "Style". Are you sure the folder is literally called `Style`, and not `style` or `styles`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@font-face{
font-family: CHERL; // Name of the font
src: url(/Style/CHERL___.ttf); 
}
```

If you are calling it directly from index.html without a style.css you should use `/Style/CHERL___.ttf`

Comment: Thank you, this is the only one that worked for some reason! 

    @font-face{
    font-family: CHERL;
    src: url(../Styles/CHERL___.ttf);
    }
    h1{
    font-family: CHERL;
    }

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the CSS file is the one that needs to find the `.tff` file. Not the index.

Try to put the CSS file and the `.tff` file in the same folder. In that way, when you call the file in the properties URL, you only have to insert the name of the `.tff` file, like this:

```
src: url(CHERL___.ttf);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already been calling style.css in your index.html like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/style.css">
```

So all you need is, in your style.css file call it like below.

```
@font-face{
font-family: CHERL___.ttf;
src: url(CHERL___.ttf);
}
```